# How to delegate the refresh token renewal in a SOA

Tags: microservices, authentication, authorization, microfrontends

So, we've got SOA on the backend (BE) and on the frontend (FE) we've got micro-frontends (the separate micro-frontends are loaded as components into the frontend app when needed, so internal process calls between them are possible, unlike the backend services, where between-process calls must be done).

On the BE we've got an `Auth` service and some other `Bananas` service. On the FE we've got also an `auth` micro-frontend and whatever other `bananas` micro-frontend. Imagine a user's `access token` has expired and he makes a request to `/bananas/create`. Each of our BE services of course validates the access token received on each request, and if invalid - return `401`. We want to implement `refresh token` functionality (the refresh token will be passed alongside the access token with each request).

Now the question is: if a request with an expired token is received:

1. should the `Bananas` service, when seeing the token is expired, make a
   call to the `Auth` service to validate the `refresh token` and receive a new pair of tokens, then perform the actual bananas business and respond with the token pairs + the actual bananas data. All in 1 call. Or...
2. should the `Bananas` still return `401`, then the bananas micro-frontend delegates to the auth micro-frontend to call the `Auth` service for new tokens, then return it to the bananas micro-frontend and it to make a new call to the `Bananas` service, with valid tokens?

This is the dilemma of design between me an my colleague. My point is that I don't want to have a 3 request-response calls back-and-forth. He argues that the `Bananas` service should always only return bananas data in its response objects, and not have cases when it also returns token pairs.

As I see it, both our points are valid, but we do not have the experience and knowledge to decide which has bigger priority/which is the better design.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.

The front end owns the auth, so the front end should manage it. Personally, I would have some thin front end layer that orchestrates the components (and handles the user/authentication/authorization needed by all of them). But your colleague is right that APIs should return the same data types for every call. Request/response/request will happen from time to time for this (and optimistic concurrency if applicable; and transient network sort of error retry) and can be mitigated by refreshing the token slightly ahead of time.